p-inputNumber button - The input value is null when using the down arrow
I'm using the p-inputNumber button in order to allow the user to select a filter value for a table column.
Unfortunately if I use the down arrow and I select the value 0 the Mouse event it is not triggered and the input value is null.
However if I enter the value 0 manually or if first time I use the up arrow to select the value 1 then the down arrow and select 0 the mouse event it is triggered and the input value is 0.
I think the issue is that the change from null to 0 is not detected.
Any ideas how can I solve this issue?
<p-inputNumber
    [ngModel]="value"
    (onInput)="onNumericChange($event, filterConstraint, false)"
    placeholder="Search"
    [showButtons]="true"
    [min]="0"
></p-inputNumber>

onNumericChange(ev: any, filter: any, isNumber: boolean) {
    const pattern = /^[0-9]+\|$/
    if (isNumber) {
        if (!pattern.test(ev.target.value)) {
            ev.target.value = ev.target.value.replace(/[^0-9\|]/g, '')
        }
        filter.value = ev.target.value
    } else {
        filter.value = ev.value
    }
}


please share a working example on stackblitz with the replication steps. you can use the stackblitz examples on primeng website

you don't need to use any method to try to test if the value contains an invalid number the component do all they work for you

To synchronize value changes, you should use [(ngModel)]="value". Without (ngModel), the value changes will not be detected or updated.
<p-inputNumber
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    placeholder="Search"
    [showButtons]="true"
    [min]="0"
  ></p-inputNumber>

The p-inputNumber component automatically filters the input to only allow numeric values, ignoring non-numeric characters. This means there's no need for additional validation functions to check the entered value.
demo 
